# loop through nested parenthesis content

Tags: java, loops, nested, parentheses

i find quite a lot of similar questions but mostly regarding regexp and not exactly what i want to do.

```
Given a string = "(content4(content3(content2(content1...))))
```

I would like to get the leaf parenthesis content first (content1...) than one level above content2 (content2(content1...)) than the next level above.. and so on. I have a few really complicated solutions, but i wonder if there is not a much simpler way. This seems to be best solved recursively, but i cant find a good solution yet. 
Somebody maybe has solved already something similar.
Do you guys have any ideas or suggestions?

thx in advance for your help, i appreciate it

ADDITION :

The string can also look like this :

string = "(content4(content3(content2(content1...);content5(content6...))))"

Comment: It looks like a normal stack probelm to me. By the way, your string is  missing a '"'.

Comment: IMHO regexp is not appropriate, a simple recursive decent parser is the way to go

Comment: Isn't there ever more then one element inside the parens?

Comment: yes there is, there can be more than one element

Answer (score 3):

Use the stack.

Divide your string into 3 types of elements.

a. left parenthesis.

b. String between two consecutive left parenthesis or if there is no second left parentheses then a string between a left parenthesis and the immediate right parenthesis.

c. right parenthesis

The approach would be something like the following.

> 1. Push the left parenthesis onto the top of stack.
> 2. push the string between two left parenthesis onto the top of the stack given that second left parenthesis does exist then goto step 3 else push the string that is in between a left and right parenthesis onto the top of the stack and goto step4.
> 3. push the left parenthesis after the string(string between two left parenthesis) onto the top of the stack. Repeat steps 1 to 3 until you encounter a right parenthesis.
> 4. Once you encountered a right parenthesis, remove the top two elements that is the string(string between two left parenthesis) or if applicable the string(string between the left and immediate right parenthesis) and the left parenthesis
>      from the stack and adjust the top index and string index. Now you have
>      the content 1.
> 5. Repeat the step 4 until you have got all the contents.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work quite nicely with sane inputs. I haven't tested with strange ones.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  ArrayList<String> split = split("(content4(content3(content2(content1...))))");
  System.out.println("Split: " + split);
}

// Standard set of braces.
private static final String openBraces = "({[<";
// Matching close set.
private static final String closeBraces = ")}]>";

public static ArrayList<String> split(String s) {
  // Default to splitting with my standard set of braces.
  return split(s, openBraces, closeBraces);
}

// Holds the start of an element and which brace started it.
private static class Start {
  // The brace number from the braces string in use.
  final int brace;
  // The position in the string it was seen.
  final int pos;

  // Constructor.
  public Start(int brace, int pos) {
    this.brace = brace;
    this.pos = pos;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "{"+openBraces.charAt(brace)+","+pos+"}";
  }
}

public static ArrayList<String> split(String s, String open, String close) {
  // The splits.
  ArrayList<String> split = new ArrayList<String>();
  // The stack.
  ArrayList<Start> stack = new ArrayList<Start>();
  // Walk the string.
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    // Get the char there.
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    // Is it an open brace?
    int o = open.indexOf(ch);
    // Is it a close brace?
    int c = close.indexOf(ch);
    if (o >= 0) {
      // Its an open! Push it.
      stack.add(new Start(o, i));
    } else if ( c >= 0 && stack.size() > 0 ) {
      // Pop (if matches).
      int tosPos = stack.size() - 1;
      Start tos = stack.get(tosPos);
      // Does the brace match?
      if ( tos.brace == c) {
        // Matches!
        split.add(s.substring(tos.pos, i+1));
        // Done with that one.
        stack.remove(tosPos);
      }
    }
  }
  return split;
}
```

prints:

```
Split: [(content1...), (content2(content1...)), (content3(content2(content1...))), (content4(content3(content2(content1...))))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it long time ago with HyperTalk, but the algorithmic frame remains the same :

1 - each time you encounter an opening brace, add 1 to your parentheses counter
2 - do the reverse thing for closing parentheses

Each time you find out the first opening parenthesis, store its position+1, do the same with position-1 for closing parenthesis.

When the closing parenthesis is found, extract the substring and recurse on it.

If you want to obtain the more nested "leaf" first, just use lists with position of the parenthesis, and read your list backwards (or use a stack).

But beware of that : this technique will only bring you the first child.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a nice solution for your problem.

```
    String str = "(content4(content3(content2(content1...))))";
    str = str.replaceFirst("\\(", "");
    String[] results = str.split("\\)")[0].split("\\(");

    int l = results.length;
    for (int j = 0; j < l / 2; j++) {
        String temp = results[j];
        results[j] = results[l - j - 1];
        results[l - j - 1] = temp;
    }

    for (String string : results) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

Code explanation:

- First we remove the first "(" because it will cause an empty string to appear at the end.
- split the string around ")" and take the string at index 0 to keep our data:

  the string would look like this now:

> content4(content3(content2(content1...

- Then by splitting again around "(" we get our content arranged in reverse.
- finally we reverse the array

Comment: Is it possible to get the nested level too? like 1 - content1..., 2 - content2 likewise

Answer (score 0):

Here goes my way to solve this issue by setting a head and tail flag on both side of brace, but the real classic way is to use stack.

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    String str = "(content4(content3(content2(content1...))))";
    int head = str.lastIndexOf("(");
    int tail = 0;

    while (head != -1) {
        // stop loop if the brace mismatch
        if (str.substring(tail, str.length()).indexOf(")") == -1)
            break;
        tail += str.substring(tail, str.length()).indexOf(")") + 1;
        String res = str.substring(head, tail);
        System.out.println(res);
        head = str.substring(0, head).lastIndexOf("(");

    }
}
```